# Transpose date range into sql rows

Tags: sql-server

I want to display all the dates between startdate and enddate into one row, technically there should be 649 rows. Been searching through web as to how to do it but failed to find one. Please help.

```
Declare @StartDate Date =‘2021-01-01  Declare @EndDate Date =‘2022-10-12

Result:

Date_R
2021-01-01
2021-01-02
2021-01-03
. . .
2022-10-12
```

Comment: That's not transposing. Transposing means converting rows to columns or vice versa. What you ask is to generate all values in a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @StartDate Date ='2021-01-01';
Declare @EndDate Date ='2022-10-12';

WITH DATES(DATED)AS
(
  SELECT @StartDate
    UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,D.DATED)
  FROM DATES AS D
  WHERE D.DATED<@EndDate
)
SELECT D.DATED
FROM DATES AS D
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Example with creating temp-table

```
Declare @StartDate Date ='2021-01-01';
Declare @EndDate Date ='2022-10-12';

IF OBJECT_ID(N'TEMPDB..#DATES',N'U')IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #DATES;

  CREATE TABLE #DATES
  (
    DATED DATE
  );

 WITH DATES(DATED)AS
 (
   SELECT @StartDate
     UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,D.DATED)
   FROM DATES AS D
   WHERE D.DATED<@EndDate
 )
 INSERT #DATES(DATED)
  SELECT D.DATED
  FROM DATES AS D
  OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)

 SELECT TOP 50* FROM #DATES;--just to show sample data

 DROP TABLE #DATES;--drop temp-table
```

Comment: Hi @Sergey, is there another way to do it without using with clause? with clause does not work if you put it in subquery. Thank you.

Comment: of course :-). Standard option is to create calendar table and use it

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: please see above the example with temp-table